# Sails.js installed globally in system npm directory, but looks inside node.js modules directory incorrectly

Tags: node.js, sails.js, windows-10

Node.js v0.12.7 was installed on **Windows 10** via the MSI installer.

Sails.js v0.11 was installed with `npm install -g sails`

But when I attempted to create a new Sails project via `sails new testProject` I got this:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\sails\bin\sails.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

The solution was to copy the Sails.js modules from the npm directory `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm` to the Node.js modules directory `C:\Program files\nodejs\node_modules`.

**The problem is...** I want to know why Sails is looking inside the Node.js modules directory, and why/how to correctly set up node/sails such that this issue would not have occurred.

Comment: Hm, sounds like an issue with your Node / NPM installation--like it tried to make an alias from the `npm` folder to `nodejs` but was unsuccessful.